# Read i-th chunk from xml file with R

Tags: r, xml, database, chunks

I downloaded some xml files from http://data.discogs.com/. Those xml files are too big to be fully loaded into my PC's memory. Thus, I'm going to read it line-wise to create a relational database. My first attempts are using `readLines()` and then parsing single chunks to lists with `xmlToList()` from the `XML` package:

```
require(XML)
entries <- readLines("artists.xml", n = 2)
chunk2  <- xmlToList(entries[2])
```

However, I haven't found a way to only read the i-th chunk (e.g. chunk 301) from the xml file (the argument `n` in `readLines()` reads all chunks from 1 to n). Thus I wonder if you can help.

Thanks a lot in advance! Every help is appreciated.